# Calling another method from a String method after it returns the string

Tags: java, string, methods

I have something I am trying to figure out.  So when I run this method called:

public String showList()

I want it to return the string, but after that call a method called displayMenu, so it will automatically go to the next method when the showList is called.  Is this possible?

The showList method: (I want to call another method called public void displayMenu())

```
public String showList()
    {
        sortList();

            int i = 0;
            String retStr = "The nodes in the list are:\n";
            LinkedListNode current = front;
            while(current != null){
                i++;
                retStr += "Node " + i + " is: " + current.getData() + "\n";
                current = current.getNext();
            }
            return retStr;
                //Would like to call the displayMenu() here, but I can't after the string returns it is unreachable.

        }
```

Comment: why not call `displayMenu` before returning the string?

Comment: You can call displayMenu() after showList() function in the function where you called showList() but you can not call any function or execute any statement after return statement in a function. You can also call displayMenu() before return statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: I don't recommend doing this. I definitely recommend that you call the methods one after another in some controller class. Now that that's done:

A rather complicated method of doing this that hasn't yet been mentioned is by using a [`Thread`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html). I would not generally do this, but it is worth noting that it can be done. Note that this is dealing with Threads (see [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html)) so I won't guarantee that the method will evaluate after the return.

One way of doing this is as follows:

In the same class as your method include something like the following:

```
class doSomething implements Runnable{
    public void run(){
        displayMenu();
    }
}
```

Then, in your `showList` method, do the following:

```
public String showList(){
    ...//some code
    (new Thread(new doSomething())).start(); //more efficient: create a 
                                             //variable to hold the thread.
    return retStr;
}
```

---

Example code:

```
public class test{
    public static void main(String[]a){
        System.out.print(foo());
    }

    public static String foo(){
        (new Thread(new fooBar())).start();
        return "foo";
    }
    public static void bar(){
        System.out.println("bar");
    }

    static class fooBar implements Runnable{
        public void run(){
            bar();
        }
    }
}
```

Prints:

> foobar

Answer (score 1):

you can not write anything after the return statement. Return statement should be the last line of a method.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your method calling `showList()` as shown below. Let's call this method is `doSomething()`

```
doSomething(){

 String output=showList(..); // This is your existing method call

 displayMenu();      // call displaymenu() once showlist() execution is over

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing about a return statement is that when you use it, you're basically saying that "I want to return this value now". Not in 5 lines, not after another function call. **Now**.

Thus, it doesn't make sense to want to do something in a method after returning a value; you've already basically indicated that there's nothing left to do; you're done and ready to go back to the calling method.

@DarkKnight and @ManZzup have already suggested alternatives; you need to restructure your code so that there's no need for such a construct.